# Network Skip Pinging Every 3 minutes periodically for 2 sec

Tags: linux, ping

I have an application runs in UP Board | UP-CHT01, which will do an operation and send the data to NATS Messaging Server. ( Which is running on another PC i.e, not in the same board)

While testing the application we found, its failing to send message for 2-3 second every 3 minute periodically.

After some debugging I figured, may be its a network problem instead of application.

So I stopped the application and I tried pinging nats server every second separately, and see, if any disconnection happens.

Simple ping - `ping -O <ipAddress>`

Same things happening, every 3 minutes - ping skips
given below, I skipped some ping logs which are not needed

```
20230402-07:13:54.078730 64 bytes from 192.168.1.239: icmp_seq=76 ttl=63 time=0.664 ms
20230402-07:13:56.125891 no answer yet for icmp_seq=77 
20230402-07:13:57.149865 no answer yet for icmp_seq=78 
20230402-07:13:58.173868 no answer yet for icmp_seq=79 
20230402-07:13:58.174764 64 bytes from 192.168.1.239: icmp_seq=80 ttl=63 time=0.663 ms
....
20230402-07:16:55.038752 64 bytes from 192.168.1.239: icmp_seq=253 ttl=63 time=0.692 ms 
20230402-07:16:57.085881 no answer yet for icmp_seq=254 
20230402-07:16:58.109875 no answer yet for icmp_seq=255 
20230402-07:16:59.133873 no answer yet for icmp_seq=256 
20230402-07:16:59.134810 64 bytes from 192.168.1.239: icmp_seq=257 ttl=63 time=0.699 ms
20230402-06:51:23.102719 490 packets transmitted, 481 received, 1.83673%
```

I did pinging google.com, same things happen.

Any body can explain, what could be the possible reason for this. Anything related to router or switches.

Comment: If the problem is with that host alone then that host is at fault. Any which way, you have provided near zero information to provide an answer.

Comment: sorry, i am new to networking and network related aspects, what kind of information you are looking, specifically @Zac67

Comment: [how to ask a good question](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)